# Waiting time for Poisson arrival and uniform pickup

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, poisson-distribution

At a station, buses leave every $t$ seconds carrying *all* the waiting people. The arrival times of these people is Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda$.

What is the expected waiting time of a passenger?

---

**Attempt**

Consider the time interval $I = [t_0, t_0+t]$. The waiting time $W$ of a passenger arriving that $t_1\in I$ is more than $w$ if they arrive in the first $t-w$ seconds of this interval, i.e., $t_1 \in I_w = [t_0, t_0+t-w]$.

Expected number of arrivals in $I$ is $\lambda t$ and that in $I_w$ is $\lambda (t-w)$.

So, a fraction $\frac{t-w}{w}$ of passengers wait for time more than $w$.

Is the last line correct?

---

PS: This is not the same as the [Waiting Time Paradox](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2018/09/13/waiting-time-paradox/), where buses arrive at Poisson-distributed times.

Comment: Waiting times of a Poisson process are exponentially distributed; see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2092/relationship-between-poisson-and-exponential-distribution

Comment: @Abezhiko I am aware of that. I don't think that is related to my question, as that is more like the pickups being Poisson distributed.